# FXML Resource isn't loading

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am developing a simple JavaFX application and I cannot load one of the resources (login.fxml), even though I can load the other that is in the same folder (main.fxml).

My folder organization is in the screenshot below. The error is in the line 50 (highlighted)

[image]

The loadVista method source code:

> ```
> public static void loadVista(String fxml) {
>     try {
>         mainController.setVista(
>             FXMLLoader.load(
>                 Navigator.class.getResource(
>                     fxml
>                 )
>             )
>         );
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
> ```

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance,
Gabriel

EDIT: a part of stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sisgem.view.Navigator.loadVista(Navigator.java:45)
at sisgem.SisGEMApplication.loadMainPane(SisGEMApplication.java:50)
at sisgem.SisGEMApplication.start(SisGEMApplication.java:25)
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code as part of your question, instead of as a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, I will do this the next time I post, Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mainController` is null, so you get a `NullPointerException` when you call `mainController.setVista(...)`. This is because you use the `static` method `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` to load the FXML, and never invoke `load` on the `FXMLLoader` instance `loader`. Since that instance never executes its `load()` method, its controller is never initialized, and `loader.getController()` returns `null`.

So your `loadMainPane()` method should look like

```
private Pane loadMainPane() throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(Navigator.class.getResource(Navigator.PANE));

    Pane mainPane = loader.load();

    MainController mainController = loader.getController();

    Navigator.setMainController(mainController);

    Navigator.loadVista("login.fxml");

    return mainPane ;
}
```